# How to redeploy a lambda function automatically after completion

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda, cryptography

I am working on a project that uses python's cryptography library to symmetrically encrypt and decrypt strings. I have a front-end interface that gathers the user's string and desired password and then uploads it to s3 as a JSON object, which triggers a lambda function to turn the password into an encryption key with a PBKDF2HMAC algorithm. Then it's used to encrypt the string. Finally, it sends the encrypted string over to aws parameter store.

All of it works, however, it only works once due to the nature of PBKDF2HMAC only being able to run once. This is the error message I get from my lambda function:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "PBKDF2 instances can only be used once.",
  "errorType": "AlreadyFinalized",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 66, in lambda_handler\n    key= base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(ekey))\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py\", line 48, in derive\n    raise AlreadyFinalized(\"PBKDF2 instances can only be used once.\")\n"
  ]
}
```

I find that I can get around this by typing a space in my lambda function's code and deleting it, then redeploying it. But this is not practical. I want my lambda to encrypt the string, and upon sending it over to parameter store, refresh the function so it can be used again right after. Any help?

Comment: Looks like others have had similar problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72189488/how-could-i-fully-restart-a-lambda-function-runtime-without-having-to-make-a-new. You can do what was suggested in that link and just add a new environmental variable forcing it to start fresh.

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer I saw that, however, I would like it to be done automatically from the lambda function itself instead of having to manually add a new environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are deploying your lambda with some kind infrastructure as a code ?

Can you setup one environment variable to be current timestamp or something ?

This way it would always change every time you rebuild this lambda and you do not need to change the code manually ?

If it works, just trigger the build/deploy from the lambda automatically after specific event.

Comment: I like this idea, I will try it and get back to you. A question though: this would create an infinite loop, where every second it would redeploy the lambda function correct? Now if it does work, will it skyrocket the price to run? Or would it be free?

Comment: Im afraid im not quite following the infinite loop.

The deployment happens in (for example) terraform or AWS CDK with specific 
command. 

You have to trigger it after specific event. So your idea is to Triger a redeploy of lambda after it was executed once ?

Imho you don't pay AWS Lambda for deploying, only for every 100 ms of running time, based on resources you use.  

Honestly, it feels like a hacky workaround :( Cant you just remake a new instance every time :/ ? Or is it to expensive :/ ? I have no knowledge about PBKDF2 instances

Comment: It is hacky.. however, I would like to finish up my project sooner rather than later. At the moment my program only has one user, but it is possible to create a login system and avoid this problem entirely.